# create runtime with two decimal places

Tags: angular, typescript, intervals

I need to create an elapsed time and display on the screen for the user as follows: **00:00:00**.

At the moment I'm doing the way it is below, but it's getting in the **0:0:0** format and I need it in the format **01:03:59**.

The user clicks start and starts calculating elapsed time.

**How can I do this?**

**in typescript:**

```
this.duration = {
  hours: 0,
  minutes: 0,
  seconds: 0
};



start(): void {
  const counter = setInterval(() => {

  this.duration.seconds += 1;

  if (this.duration.minutes === 60) {
    this.duration.hour += 1;
  }

  if (this.duration.seconds === 60) {
    this.duration.minutes += 1;
  }

  if (this.duration.seconds === 60) {
    this.duration.seconds = 0;
  }

}, 1000)
```

}

**in html:**

```
{{ duration.hours }}:{{ duration.minutes }}:{{ duration.seconds }}
```

Comment: Does the timer run for a long time? Is there some activity that may delay the interval ticks? Using time difference is more reliable than counting interval ticks, as shown in [this stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-hp2hjy?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts) (perform heavy calculation while the timers are running to see the difference).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use existing angular number pipe for each part

```
{{ duration.hours | number:'2.0-0'}}:{{ duration.minutes | number:'2.0-0'}}:{{ duration.seconds | number:'2.0-0'}}
```

this way if number of your hours exceeds 99 also it will display correctly

---

```
{minIntegerDigits}.{minFractionDigits}-{maxFractionDigits}.

minIntegerDigits: The minimum number of integer digits before the decimal point. Default is 1.
minFractionDigits: The minimum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 0.
maxFractionDigits: The maximum number of digits after the decimal point. Default is 3.
```

Working [Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-date-format-pipe-psqfad?file=app/hello.component.ts)

Comment: his numbers wont exceed 99 he has `  if (this.duration.seconds === 60) {`

Comment: @dota2pro I was talking about `hours`, there is no check for hours in the code. it will increment infinitely

Answer (score 0):

Hi You Achieve this by using **[Angular pipe](https://angular.io/api/common/DatePipe)**

```
<div>{{time| date:'HH:mm:ss'}}</div> 12:01:59
```

Comment: I do not want to work with date, I just want to get the time elapsed after the user clicks on start.

Answer (score 0):

You can write your own pipe, like so:

```
import _ from 'lodash';
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

// ...

@Pipe({name: 'doubleDigits'})
export class DoubleDigitsPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(value: any) {
    return _.isNumber(value) && value <= 9 ? "0"+value : value;
  }
}

// HTML

{{ duration.hours | doubleDigits }}:{{ duration.minutes | doubleDigits }}:{{ duration.seconds | doubleDigits }}
```

This will convert your number to a string in the template, but I don't think that should cause problems.